# how to extract rows which match based on two conditions from two dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, conditional-statements, rbind

I have two dataframe one is snp region and other is Hic region.

```
dput(hic_region[1:15,1:4])
structure(list(rf1 = c(57584944, 57584944, 57584944, 57584944, 
57584944, 57584944, 57584944, 57584944, 50263463, 5e+07, 50263463, 
50263463, 35172197, 35172197, 57584944), rt1 = c(57624944, 57624944, 
57624944, 57624944, 57624944, 57624944, 57624944, 57624944, 50303463, 
51423463, 50303463, 50303463, 35212197, 35212197, 57624944), 
    rf2 = c(1899354, 1899354, 1899354, 1899354, 1899354, 1579354, 
    1899354, 1899354, 1899354, 1779354, 1899354, 1899354, 1899354, 
    1899354, 1499354), rt2 = c(1939354, 1939354, 1939354, 1939354, 
    1939354, 1619354, 1939354, 1939354, 1939354, 1819354, 1939354, 
    1939354, 1939354, 1939354, 1539354)), row.names = c(NA, -15L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
> dput(snp_region[1:10,1:6])
structure(list(Gene = c("ENSG00000132819", "ENSG00000101162", 
"ENSG00000132819", "ENSG00000101162", "ENSG00000101162", "ENSG00000101162", 
"ENSG00000101162", "ENSG00000101162", "ENSG00000101162", "ENSG00000101162"
), `Gene-Chr` = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20), `Gene-Pos` = c(55975426, 
57598009, 55975426, 57598009, 57598009, 57598009, 57598009, 57598009, 
57598009, 57598009), RsId = c("rs6084653", "rs156356", "rs1741314", 
"rs6136489", "rs4814776", "rs13042885", "rs4814779", "rs6045615", 
"rs11696739", "rs4618126"), `SNP-Chr` = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 20), `SNP-Pos` = c(4157072, 1819280, 4155193, 
1923734, 1921523, 1924707, 1923271, 1931582, 1600925, 1930885
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I want to match the gene present in snp region to hic region from rf1 to rt1, if its present between these two region(rf1 and rt1), select that and then match snp position from snp region using rf2 and rt2 region.
I wrote a code but it gives me repeated values.

```
snp <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:dim(snp_region)[1]){
  snp_pos <- snp_region$`SNP-Pos`[i]
  for(j in 1:dim(hic_region)[1]){
  if(snp_region$`Gene-Pos`[i] %in% seq(hic_region$rf1[j],hic_region$rt1[j],1)){
   hic_region1 <- hic_region[j,]
    if(snp_pos %in% seq(hic_region1$rf2,hic_region1$rt2,1)){
      preset <<- snp_region[i,]
    } 
  }
  }
  snp <- rbind(snp,preset)
}


dput(snp[1:5,1:6])
structure(list(Gene = c("ENSG00000131069", "ENSG00000131069", 
"ENSG00000131069", "ENSG00000101162", "ENSG00000101162"), `Gene-Chr` = c(20, 
20, 20, 20, 20), `Gene-Pos` = c(33487859, 33487859, 33487859, 
57598009, 57598009), RsId = c("rs4142441", "rs4142441", "rs4142441", 
"rs6136489", "rs4814776"), `SNP-Chr` = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20), 
    `SNP-Pos` = c(42839620, 42839620, 42839620, 1923734, 1921523
    )), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I wanted to get some feedback if I am doing something wrong, or if there is a better way to run two conditions to match rows for two dataframe.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another option using `data.table`. This process is called a `non-equi` join.

In the `on` portion, you can create logic for `Gene-Pos` to be between `rt1` and `rf2` AND `SNP-Pos` to be between `rf2` and `rt2`. Then select the columns you want included across both tables.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(hic_region)
setDT(snp_region)

matched_genes = unique(snp_region[
  hic_region, 
  on = .(`Gene-Pos` >= rf1, `Gene-Pos` <= rt1, `SNP-Pos` >= rf2, `SNP-Pos` <= rt2), 
  .(Gene, `Gene-Chr`, `Gene-Pos`=`x.Gene-Pos`, RsId, `SNP-Chr`, `SNP-Pos`=`x.SNP-Pos`, rf1, rt1, rf2, rt2), 
  nomatch = NULL
])

matched_genes
```

```
# Output

              Gene Gene-Chr Gene-Pos       RsId SNP-Chr SNP-Pos      rf1      rt1     rf2     rt2
1: ENSG00000101162       20 57598009  rs6136489      20 1923734 57584944 57624944 1899354 1939354
2: ENSG00000101162       20 57598009  rs4814776      20 1921523 57584944 57624944 1899354 1939354
3: ENSG00000101162       20 57598009 rs13042885      20 1924707 57584944 57624944 1899354 1939354
4: ENSG00000101162       20 57598009  rs4814779      20 1923271 57584944 57624944 1899354 1939354
5: ENSG00000101162       20 57598009  rs6045615      20 1931582 57584944 57624944 1899354 1939354
6: ENSG00000101162       20 57598009  rs4618126      20 1930885 57584944 57624944 1899354 1939354
7: ENSG00000101162       20 57598009 rs11696739      20 1600925 57584944 57624944 1579354 1619354
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below code where you get the same records as in `snp_region`

Here you will get 2 `flg`

`flg` represents the snp region to hic region from rf1 to rt1, if its present between these two region(rf1 and rt1)

`flg2` represents a match of snp position from snp region using rf2 and rt2 region.

```r
library(tidyverse)

snp_region2 <- snp_region %>% mutate(row=row_number())

snp_region2 %>% cross_join(hic_region) %>% 
  mutate(flg=ifelse(between(`Gene-Pos`,rf1,rt1),1,NA),
         flg2=ifelse(flg==1 & between(`SNP-Pos`,rf2,rt2),1,NA)) %>% 
  group_by(row) %>% slice_head(n=1) %>% filter(!is.na(flg)|!is.na(flg2))

# output 

# A tibble: 8 × 13
# Groups:   row [8]
  Gene      `Gene-Chr` `Gene-Pos` RsId  `SNP-Chr` `SNP-Pos`   row    rf1    rt1    rf2
  <chr>          <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 ENSG0000…         20   57598009 rs15…        20   1819280     2 5.76e7 5.76e7 1.90e6
2 ENSG0000…         20   57598009 rs61…        20   1923734     4 5.76e7 5.76e7 1.90e6
3 ENSG0000…         20   57598009 rs48…        20   1921523     5 5.76e7 5.76e7 1.90e6
4 ENSG0000…         20   57598009 rs13…        20   1924707     6 5.76e7 5.76e7 1.90e6
5 ENSG0000…         20   57598009 rs48…        20   1923271     7 5.76e7 5.76e7 1.90e6
6 ENSG0000…         20   57598009 rs60…        20   1931582     8 5.76e7 5.76e7 1.90e6
7 ENSG0000…         20   57598009 rs11…        20   1600925     9 5.76e7 5.76e7 1.90e6
8 ENSG0000…         20   57598009 rs46…        20   1930885    10 5.76e7 5.76e7 1.90e6
# ℹ 3 more variables: rt2 <dbl>, flg <dbl>, flg2 <dbl>
```

Comment: I like this solution! Nice application for `dplyr::between()`.  I think you can omit the `ifelse()` and simply use the condition to create a `logical`, which is usually more useful for downstream tasks. Like: `flg=between(\`Gene-Pos\`, rf1, rt1)`

Comment: I am a SAS programmer so got used to creating the flag variables like that. But I agree with your comment. Thank you

Comment: The answer you selected returns 7 rows and my answer returns 8, i am curious to know which is correct

Comment: @jkatam - I believe OP wants the gene included if `Gene-Pos` and `SNP-Pos` are within the bounds of the rf/rt variables. e.g. for the same row. In your output the gene with `RsId == rs156356` only meets half of the criteria. `Gene-Pos` matches but `SNP-Pos` does not.